# dynamic buttons and on.click event issue

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I'm generating dynamic css buttons with unique id's and I'm capturing the click event with the following click handler

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'a', function() {
    if (typeof(this.id) != "undefined") { //check if id exists
        var n = this.id.split("%");
        if (n[0] == "jsonpbtn") { //check if one of our buttons    
            var surl = "http://www.blah.com/tree/jsonp/foo/" + n[1];
            $.ajax({
                url: surl,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp: false,
                jsonpCallback: 'foo',
                error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + ":" + errorThrown)
                },
                success: function(foo) {
                    $('#blah' + foo.id).html(foo.message);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});​
```

Although the ajax call works the page generates an error "parsererror:Error: foo was not called"; I believe the problem is this loops through all the "a" elements on the page and 
calls the function for each "jsonpbtn"?

Comment: The problem is `http://www.blah.com/tree/jsonp/foo/n[1]` isn't returning a JSONP function named `foo`. the response should look like `foo({"foo":"bar"})`

Comment: agree with Kevin B. It is on the serverside, it is simply malformed JSONP, _foo was not called_ occurs when there is no `foo ( JSON )`

Comment: as stated the ajax call works and if I have only one button on the page there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by inserting a preliminary stage before the ajax call where I change the button status fixes the issue.

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'a', function() {
if (typeof(this.id) != "undefined") { //check if id exists
    var n = this.id.split("%");
    if (n[0] == "jsonpbtn") { //check if one of our buttons    
        var surl = "http://www.blah.com/tree/jsonp/foo/" + n[1];
        $('#div_id'+n[1]).html('<a class="button" href="#">working</a>');//<-added this
        $.ajax({
            url: surl,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'foo',
            error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + ":" + errorThrown)
            },
            success: function(foo) {
                $('#blah' + foo.id).html(foo.message);
            }
        });
    }
}
});​
```

Thanks to those who tried to help.
Regards
Martin